# Windows Phone: Move focus to text box when keyboard enter is pressed/

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a windows phone page with the following UI markup:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBox Name="txtName"/>
    <PasswordBox Name="txtPassword"/>
    <Button Name="btnLogin" Content="Login"/>
<StackPanel>
```

What I want to do: After the user types the user name and clicks the "Enter" key on the keyboard, I want the focus to move to the next "txtPassword" `TextBox`  , then when presses "Enter" the focus moves to the button and so on...

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Xaml:**

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBox x:Name="txtName" KeyDown="TxtName_KeyDown" />
            <PasswordBox x:Name="txtPassword" KeyDown="TxtPassword_KeyDown"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnLogin" Content="Login" />
        </StackPanel>
```

---

**Cs:**

```
        private void TxtName_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
                txtPassword.Focus();
        }

        private void TxtPassword_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
                btnLogin.Focus();
        }
```

---

Useful info: [Determining the Enter key is pressed in a TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295057/determining-the-enter-key-is-pressed-in-a-textbox)

Comment: @Mina Samy I'm glad to hear it.